# Firebase iOS / Swift and Deep Links

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

We have just integrated firebase, and all of a sudden our deep links are no longer working.  We're using AppAuth for authentication, so we're reliant on deep links to direct us to the right place.  I'm getting the following error:

```
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {...}
```

Initialization of firebase as follows:

```
let bundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-" + bundleId!, ofType: "plist")!
let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
FIRApp.configure(with: options!)
```

And here's the deep linking functions:

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: nil, annotation: [:])
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        if url.host == AppHost.deeplink {
        ...
   }
```

If i remove the call to FIRApp.configure, everything in the app works fine.  My AppAuth redirects flow into the function above without any issue.  However, with the call to configure(), it never gets into either one of the functions.  As a result, i can't do a token exchange and complete authentication.

I suspected the AppDelegate proxy might be the issue, so i tried disabling it in the plist file.  I've validated that the plist file passed to FIRApp.configure has the appropriate keys:

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

But no matter what i do, it's still activating the proxy:

```
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
```

I'm using only FirebaseCrash and FirebaseCore (and FirebaseAnalytics indirectly through crash)

Comment: Are you adding the `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` key to your app's `info.plist`? Also, what do you mean by `the plist file passed to FIRApp.configure`? How are you passing a plist file to `configure`?

Comment: @Mark see the above initialization code for how i'm doing that.  and the plist file that gets loaded has the key (again, see the snippet above from the plist file)

Comment: Also note that i've tried this by using a default bundle file "GoogleServices-Info.plist" with the default version of FIRApp.configure() with the same result.  The behavior is always the same.  Also note that crash logging is working, so it's picking up on the properties require to connect to firebase and log the crashes.

Comment: I was able to disable the proxy by adding the key to my App's `info.plist`, and using the default version of `FIRApp.configure()`. I don't think you need to edit the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` once it's created.

Comment: OK.  So you're saying i edited the wrong plist file?  I should be putting that key in the app's main plist file?  Seems odd, but ok.

Comment: If that's the issue, I can write up an answer for you to accept.

Comment: I will give it a try.  But it still doesn't answer why the deep links don't work.  At some point the future, i may need the proxy and then i'd be hosed. [Edit]: It worked, though as i said, it's not a long term solution, it's a band aid for the bigger issue of the proxy breaking the deep links.

Comment: The proxy is just a convenience thing. You shouldn't ever require it. You just need to implement what it does manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of adding the `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` key to the `GoogleServices-Info.plist`, add it to your App's `info.plist`. The Google Services plist should not be modified once it's generated.

As for disabling the proxy, it's fine to do this long term. The proxy is a convenience thing (it's just swizzling some methods), and you can reimplement it manually. There's some examples [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm) of how to handle the lack of the proxy (non-swizzling case).

Comment: let me check with my other team members on monday to make sure this is working for them as well.  Technically, i'm an android developer, but I'm helping out with the iOS stuff because they were having trouble with it.  If it passes their tests, i'll mark this as the answer.