# I have implemented Dynamic link setup now when the link is clicked i want land the app into new page.How can i check link clicked or not?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have set up a dynamic link with firebase now I want to know whether the link is clicked or not.

I have already added function:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return application(app, open: url,
                       sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                       annotation: "")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
        // Handle the deep link. For example, show the deep-linked content or
        // apply a promotional offer to the user's account.
        // ...
        print("dynamic link \(dynamicLink.url)")

        return true
    }
    return false
}


private func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in

        print("dynamic link \(dynamiclink?.url)")

    }

    return handled

    //return true
}
```

I want to know how do I know the link is clicked or not? So that I can open a view for link Click

Comment: can you explain your problem in more details??

Comment: I want to open different view if dynamic link is clicked but when i click the link app is open but non of the above function called.It show's dynamic link don't have required parameter in log.

Comment: are you using any custom URL scheme other than firebase provided one??

Comment: i am using link generated from postman.I am testing it by direct installing in phone.

Comment: have you checked this video https://youtu.be/KLBjAg6HvG0

Comment: watched but cannot find solution.

Comment: which method gets called when you tap on the dynamic link??

Comment: check if you have set correct domain in associated domain correctly

Comment: Thats exactly the problem non of the method is called while clicking the link only app is open these method is called only if i uninstall the app and reinstall it.it shows  Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    "_osl" = "https://ttnfleetsolutions.page.link/azrN2YkJQncowdQ78";
    link = "https://www.ttnfleetsolutions.com/";

Comment: yes i have set correct domain in associated domain

Comment: Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    "_cpb" = 1;
    "_cpt" = cpit;
    "_fpb" = "CJsFEPcCGgVlbi1VUw==";
    "_iumchkactval" = 1;
    "_iumenbl" = 1;
    "_osl" = "https://ttnfleetsolutions.page.link/azrN2YkJQncowdQ78";
    "_plt" = 4869;
    "_uit" = 5900;
    apn = "com.ttnfleetsolutions.ttnfleet.debug";
    cid = 1139602518769363467;
    ibi = "com.ttnfleetsolutions.ttnfleetCustomer";
    link = "https://www.ttnfleetsolutions.com/";
} while clicking link don't call any function

Comment: I will try to find out the solutions.. can you share the source code you are working with

Comment: source code of appdelegate methode?

Comment: have you added app store id in firebase dynamic link setup??

Comment: check this answer it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43152296/3278326

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger can i get your hangout id ? so that we can talk?

Comment: restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) is solved my problem bro thank you for your support.. can you provide me any id to chat i have a another problem also.